# iOS location permission request showing only english while other keys are working

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native

I have a working localisation in English and German for other keys like *NSMicrophoneUsageDescription*, *NSCameraUsageDescription* .... and they are all working.

But the permission request for location is always showing English text. I have added the following 3 keys for location in en.lproj and de.lproj folders:

```
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription = "my text"
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription = "my text"
NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription = "my text"
```

Just like the other keys, I have added those 3 keys in Info.plist and set the value empty as such:

```
  <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
  <string/>
  <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
  <string/>
  <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
  <string/>
```

All the other keys for camera, voice are done the exact same way but only location translation is not working. If I completely remove the keys from the english folder, no description will be shown. Just empty, it couldn't find the keys in German. I copy pasted every key to make sure there is no typo.

And this only happens on a real device. It works correctly on a simulator.

Is there something that had to be done for location keys only?

Answer (score 0):

If you can do it, with custom keys, referencing it in a string file, look at the following link to know how to do it

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html